# Vertex= (0,2) epicentre=(3,2) What is the name and equation of this conic?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections

Vertex= (0,2) epicentre=(3,2) What is the name and equation  of this conic?

Can i use this formula (y-B)*2 = 4a(x-A) { Here A,B is the value  of vertex }

Comment: If Epicenter which means Focus, and Vertex are given, its not possible to find what type of conic it is, because lets say if its an ellipse, so it has two epicenters (-3,2),(3,2) and vertex is also (0,2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be an ellipse depending on if there are co-vertices.  I'm not sure what you mean by the "epicenter", maybe the focus if it's a parabola?

Comment: No Sir, The question doesn't mention about another co-vertex or focus .  And the epicenter is the focus.  So the question said that there is a vertex and a focus find out the equation and name of this conic. Thank you sir for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly a parabola since the equation is of the standard form $$y^2=4ax$$
The curve has been translated so that instead of the vertex being at the origin, it is now at $(A,B)$.